What is this weed or grass?
Can someone please tell me what is this weed that is in my yard? We are in Southeast Wisconsin, with a dense clay soil that was agricultural land about three years ago, with nearby farmland still. I planted “contractors mix” seed, but this is coming up — even in the front yard where I haven’t planted yet. It looks a little like yellow nutsedge, but I haven’t seen any seeds on the taller plants, and the stem is round, not triangular. The leaves don’t seem to split with an auricle, so I don’t think it’s quack grass. The stem is purple and the white roots run mostly horizontal.



Did you put straw down?  I had a ton of something similar here in Ohio.  I suspect that it was wheat from the straw I put down or annual ryegrass.  Either way, I am hoping it dies off in winter.  Mine germinated in spring and now with mowing and the heat of summer, it is no longer growing higher than the rest of the lawn. I think it is dying off.

@EvilElf No straw, but this was previously farmland. I clarified in the post.

"Lolium is a genus of tufted grasses[...]". Good luck from there. It's insanely invasive through root formations.
